# JQuery Post JSON to MVC not redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, http-post

I'm trying load a page which I have passed some JSON as a POST. The JSON is sent and page returned, but with the below javascript I remain on the original page. I need to redirect to page

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
                var jsonObjects = {
                    "SomeJson": "SomeData"
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
                    beforeSend: function (x) {
                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                        }
                    },
                    url: 'Home'
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

This posts the JSON but the page but does not redirect. The page 'Home' is returned to the browser.

I can't redirect to home on success as the post arguments won't be present

I have tried doing this without javascript and submitting with standard html, but can't seem to embed the JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you make an ajax request and the server responds with a 3xx redirect, the page the request was made from won't change. This is because any ajax request wont change the current location in a browser, which is the very reason you usually WANT to use ajax.

So you need a success handler that you can do the redirect in. Pass this to your `$.ajax()` call.

```
success: function() {
  window.location.href = '/Home'; // or something
}
```

Which will change the current page to a url of your choice, if the request is successful.

Comment: Unfortunately a success handler will perform a GET (correct me if i'm wrong) so won't  contain the POST body. The contents of 'Home' is dependent on the JSON. Cheers

Comment: You a redirect is always a GET. You can't 3xx redirect a POST request and have it make another POST request. Browsers just won't do that. Perhaps you need to rethink your approach?

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Ajax is not a requirement, do you know of a way to make a post containing JSON that changes location?

Comment: For anyone interested, This is my current work around:  <form id='frmRequest' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' method='post' action='/Home'><input type='hidden' id='data' name='data' value="{SomeJson:  'SomeData'}">